# Adding a main class to my game so I can make a jar file

Tags: java, applet, awt

I made a game in java to practice mouse accuracy on JGrasp with the little knowledge I have with programming. Now I'm trying to create a jar file for it. However, I don't have a main class and I just run it within JGrasp at the moment. I've been trying to figure out how to run it with a main class but all the things I tried didn't work. My understanding is really low. I have no idea what to do. I don't know how to make it so my code can be accessed by a main method.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Timer;

public class Aim extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener, ComponentListener {
    // position of center circle (coordinates)
    private int scale = 500; // decide size of game
    private int seed; 
    private int turn;
    private Dimension size;
    private Image image;
    private Image background;
    private Image gameOverImg;
    private Image timerImgOnes;
    private Image timerImgTens;
    private Image timerImgMins;
    private Image timerImgColon;
    private Image scorePerMinImg;
    private Image speedUpImg;
    private Image lifeImg;
    private Image yourTime;
    private Graphics g;

    private double targetScale = 6; // scale of targets (higher number = smaller targets)
    private double originalTargetScale = targetScale;
    private int circleScale = (int) (scale / targetScale);
    private int circleScale2 = (int) (scale / (targetScale*1.35));

    private int originalCircleScale = circleScale;
    private int originalCircleScale2 = circleScale2;

    private int eraseScale = (int) (scale / (targetScale-(targetScale*.1)));
    private int eraseOffset = circleScale / 2;
    private int mx = (scale/2) - (circleScale2/2);
    private int my = mx;
    private int mxO = mx;
    private int myO = mx;
    private double distScale = 1.3; // scale of how close the targets will be to each other
    private int flick = 1;
    private int flick2 = 1;

    long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
    double elapsedSeconds = tDelta / 1000.0;

    private int gameOver;
    private int newGame;
    private int life = 3; // amount of lives
    // used to determine users score per minute
    private double score = 1;
    private double scorePerMin;
    private double requiredScorePerMin;
    private int difficulty = 30; // Choose difficulty of speed. Lower # is harder

    private int distance1 = (int) Math.hypot(circleScale*distScale, circleScale*distScale);
    private int distance2 = (int) (circleScale * distScale);

    // array for possible spots for the outer circle to spawn
    private int[] mx2 = { mx + distance1, mx + distance2, mx + distance2, mx, mx, mx-distance1, mx-distance2, mx-distance2,  };
    private int[] my2 = { my, my-distance2, my+distance2, my-distance1, my+distance1, my, my-distance2, my+distance2,  };

    Random random = new Random();
    Thread runner;
    Timer T = new Timer();

    // variables & array to paint timer & speed bar
    private String[] timerImgArray = { "res/zero.png", "res/one.png", "res/two.png", "res/three.png", "res/four.png", "res/five.png", "res/six.png", "res/seven.png", "res/eight.png", "res/nine.png"  };
    private int ones;
    private int tens;
    private int mins;
    private int timerDisplayScale;
    private int timerCenter;
    private int temp;
    private int elapsedSecondsShort;
    private int c;
    private int timerDisplacement;
    private int scoreBarSize;
    private String[] lifeImgArray = { "res/life0.png", "res/life1.png", "res/life2.png", "res/life3.png" };

    public void start() {
       if (runner == null) {
           runner = new Thread(this);
           long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
           runner.start();
       }
    }

    public void run() {
         while (true) {
         if (life > 0) {
            // Timer used for gametime display & score per minute calculation
            tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
            elapsedSeconds = tDelta / 1000.0;
            temp = (int)(elapsedSeconds*1);
            elapsedSecondsShort = ((int)temp)/1;
            c++;
            if (requiredScorePerMin > scorePerMin) {
               life = 0; 
               gameOver=1;
            }

            // calculate score per minute & required score per minute
            scorePerMin = 60 * (score / elapsedSeconds);
            requiredScorePerMin = 60 * (1 + (elapsedSeconds / difficulty));

            // update all variables each frame
            circleScale = (int) (scale / targetScale);
            circleScale2 = (int) (scale / (targetScale*1.35));
            eraseScale = (int) (scale / (targetScale-(targetScale*.1)));
            eraseOffset = circleScale / 2;
            mx = (scale/2) - (circleScale2/2);
            my = mx;
            distance1 = (int) Math.hypot(circleScale*distScale, circleScale*distScale);
            distance2 = (int) (circleScale * distScale);
            int zoomSize1 = (int)(scale/(originalCircleScale2/2.5));
            int zoomSize2 = (int)(scale/(originalCircleScale/2.5));
            // Calculates how much each circle will change in size throughout each zoom
            if (Math.abs(circleScale - originalCircleScale) >= zoomSize1) flick*=-1;
            if (Math.abs(circleScale2 - originalCircleScale2) >= zoomSize2) flick2*=-1;
            // increases & decreases the size of targets
            if (turn == 1){
               if (flick2==-1) targetScale+= .05; 
               else targetScale-= .05;
            }
            if (turn == 0){
               if (flick==-1) targetScale+= .05; 
               else targetScale-= .05; 
            }
            // updates coordinates of outer circle
            if (turn==1){
               switch (seed) {
                  case 0:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO + distance1;
                     my2[seed] = myO;
                     break;
                  case 1:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO + distance2;
                     my2[seed] = myO - distance2;
                     break;
                  case 2:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO + distance2;
                     my2[seed] = myO + distance2;
                     break;
                  case 3:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO;
                     my2[seed] = myO - distance1;
                     break;
                  case 4:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO;
                     my2[seed] = myO + distance1;
                     break;
                  case 5:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO - distance1;
                     my2[seed] = myO;
                     break;
                  case 6:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO - distance1;
                     my2[seed] = myO - distance2;
                     break;
                  case 7:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO - distance2;
                     my2[seed] = myO - distance2;
                     break;
                  case 8:
                     mx2[seed] = mxO - distance2;
                     my2[seed] = my + distance2;
                     break;
               }
            }            
            // Finish updating variables
             repaint();
             if (life == 0) {
               stop();
             }
             try { Thread.sleep(7); }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
       if (runner != null) {
           runner.stop();
           runner = null;
       }
     }

    public void init() {
        setSize(scale, scale);
        size = getSize();
        addMouseListener(this);
        background = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/background.jpg");
        gameOverImg = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/gameOver.jpg");
        image = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/aim.png");
        scorePerMinImg = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/SPM.png");
        speedUpImg = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/speedUp.png");
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        Dimension newSize = getSize();
        if (size.equals(newSize)) {
        paint(g);
        }
    }
    // paint center circle
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      if (gameOver != 1){
         if (turn == 0){
            flick2 = -1;
            scoreBarSize = (int) (scorePerMin - requiredScorePerMin);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, scale, scale, this);

            timerDisplay();
            g.drawImage(timerImgOnes, timerCenter + (timerDisplayScale / 2), 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(timerImgTens, timerCenter + (timerDisplayScale / 4), 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(timerImgMins, timerCenter - (timerDisplayScale/4), 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(timerImgColon, timerCenter, 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(scorePerMinImg, (scale/2) - scoreBarSize/2, scale - (scale/20), scoreBarSize, originalCircleScale2 / 4, this);
            if (scoreBarSize < 35) g.drawImage(speedUpImg, (scale/2) - (originalCircleScale2/2), scale - (scale/11), scale/8, scale/20, this);
            lifeImg = getImage(getDocumentBase(), lifeImgArray[life]);
            g.drawImage(lifeImg, scale - (scale/14), (scale/2) - (originalCircleScale2/2), scale / 15, scale / 6, this);

            g.drawImage(image, mx, my , circleScale2, circleScale2, this);
         } else { // paint outer, moving circle
            flick = -1;
            scoreBarSize = (int) (scorePerMin - requiredScorePerMin);
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, scale, scale, this);
            g.drawImage(image, mx2[seed], my2[seed], circleScale, circleScale, this);

            timerDisplay();
            g.drawImage(timerImgOnes, timerCenter + (timerDisplayScale / 2), 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(timerImgTens, timerCenter + (timerDisplayScale / 4), 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(timerImgMins, timerCenter - (timerDisplayScale/4), 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(timerImgColon, timerCenter, 25 , originalCircleScale2 / 2, originalCircleScale2 / 2, this);
            g.drawImage(scorePerMinImg, (scale/2) - scoreBarSize/2, scale - (scale/20), scoreBarSize, originalCircleScale2 / 4, this);
            if (scoreBarSize < 35) g.drawImage(speedUpImg, (scale/2) - (originalCircleScale2/2), scale - (scale/11), scale/8, scale/20, this);
            lifeImg = getImage(getDocumentBase(), lifeImgArray[life]);
            g.drawImage(lifeImg, scale - (scale/14), (scale/2) - (originalCircleScale2/2), scale / 15, scale / 6, this);
         }
      } else{
         g.drawImage(gameOverImg, 0, 0, scale, scale, this);
         g.drawImage(timerImgOnes, scale - scale/3 + (timerDisplayScale / 2) - timerDisplayScale/3, scale - scale/7 , (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, this);
         g.drawImage(timerImgTens, scale - scale/3 + (timerDisplayScale / 4) - timerDisplayScale/3, scale - scale/7 , (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, this);
         g.drawImage(timerImgMins, scale - scale/3 - (timerDisplayScale / 4) - timerDisplayScale/3, scale - scale/7 , (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, this);
         g.drawImage(timerImgColon, scale - scale/3 - timerDisplayScale/3, scale - scale/7 , (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, (originalCircleScale2/3)*2, this);
         g.drawImage(yourTime, timerCenter - ((timerDisplayScale*2)), scale - (scale/6) , scale/2, scale / 9, this);
      }
    }

    // updating the timer images
    public void timerDisplay(){
      if ((c == 128) && (ones != 9)) {
         ones++;
         c = 0;
      }
      if ((ones == 9) && ( c == 128)){
         tens++;
         ones = 0;
         c = 0;
      }
      if ((tens == 5) && (ones == 9) && (c == 128)) {
         mins++;
         tens = 0;
         ones = 0;
         c = 0;
      }
      timerDisplacement =  timerDisplayScale/4;
      timerDisplayScale = scale / 5;
      timerCenter = (scale / 2) - timerDisplacement;
      timerImgOnes = getImage(getDocumentBase(), timerImgArray[ones]);
      timerImgTens = getImage(getDocumentBase(), timerImgArray[tens]);
      timerImgMins = getImage(getDocumentBase(), timerImgArray[mins]);
      timerImgColon = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/colon.png");
      yourTime = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "res/yourTime.png");
    }

    /*
     * Mouse methods
     */

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {     

        if (turn == 0) seed = random.nextInt(8); 
        if (turn == 1) turn = 0; else turn = 1;

        targetScale = originalTargetScale; // reset size of circle each time it is spawned
        if (Math.abs(circleScale - originalCircleScale) >= 20) flick*=-1;
        if (Math.abs(circleScale2 - originalCircleScale2) >= 20) flick2*=-1;
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        e.consume();
        requestFocus();

        int xDif = x - mx - (circleScale2 / 2);
        int yDif = y - my - (circleScale2 / 2);
        int xDif2 = x - mx2[seed] - (circleScale / 2);
        int yDif2 = y - my2[seed] - (circleScale / 2);
        if (gameOver != 1){
           //determine if hit
           if ((Math.hypot(xDif, yDif) <= (circleScale2 / 2) && turn == 1) || (Math.hypot(xDif2, yDif2) <= (circleScale / 2) && turn == 0)){
               score++;
               getAppletContext().showStatus("HIT");
               play(getCodeBase(), "sounds/hit.au");
           }
           else {   //miss
               life--; 
               if (life == 0) {
                  gameOver=1;
               }
               getAppletContext().showStatus("MISSED");
               play(getCodeBase(), "sounds/whoosh.au");
           }
         }
      repaint();
      } 

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
        removeMouseListener(this);
    }

    public String getAppletInfo() {
        return "Title: Mouse Accuracy";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Aim extends java.applet.Applet` **java.applet.Applet**?! Swing replaced AWT quite some time ago now; I had hair and two fewer children (they're teens now) the last time I used AWT. You could make it a `JFrame`, but this looks like straight AWT code and I wonder where you found it.

Comment: I started on this from some code my professor gave me. I'll send it here. https://ufile.io/77p07

Comment: `Applet` is deprecated since java 9 without a replacement. Using it today is riding a dead horse. And if your professor uses this for teaching - well that's like you want to take driving lessons and your teacher harnesses a horse to a coach.

Answer (score 0):

The java main method is:

```
public static void main(String [ ] args){
  //do stuff
}
```

Put your starting method in and it will run fine.
I would still recommend you the swing JFrame instead of the applet bc it is way more updated and handy in my opinion.

Comment: *"Put your starting method in and it will run fine."* Did you actually try that? Just looking at the code, I can see a number of reasons why it would fail. Even a `JFrame` that instantiates the applet (calls the `init()`  & `start()` methods) and adds it to the frame would fail, as the applet as-is requires the applet context that is (by default) not available to non-applet GUIs.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Just tired to give him the main method he asked for. In a normal class or with a JFrame this usally works though.

Comment: Thanks I tried this before but didn't know why it didn't work I'll definitely use JFrame in the future lol